# What's the best way to read parameters of a function in php?

Tags: php, variables

In the past few years I've used this formula to read parameters in my methods inside my php classes:

```
$params = func_get_args();
if(is_array($params[0])){
    foreach($params[0] as $key => $value){
        ${$key} = $value;
    }
}
```

And it works fine, as if I pass something like this:

```
$class->foo(array('bar' => 'hello', 'planet' => 'world'));
```

I will have in my foo method the variables *bar* and *planet* with their relative values. 
But what I'm asking is: Is there any better way to do it? Something that maybe I can encapsulate in another method for example?

**UPDATE**

So, taking in consideration **rizier123** comment, and after a chat with a friend of mine, I nailed down what I think is the better way pass parameters to function. As I know that I will always pass just one parameter to the function, which is always going to be an array, there's no need to call the func_get_args() function, but I better to expect an array all the time and by default I set an empty array, like in the following example:

```
class MyClass{
    public function MyMethod(array $options = array()){            
        extract($options);             
    }
}

$my = new MyClass();
$my->MyMethod(array('name' => 'john', 'surname' => 'doe'));
// Now MyMethod has two internal vars called $name and $surname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use [`extract()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) to convert your arrays to variables, like this:

```
extract($params[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks, at least I can get rid of the foreach loop! But there's anyway to have it in a separated method so I just need to call it and have the vars ready in my function?

Comment: @AlessioMichelini Why do you want it in a separate function?

Comment: with the original idea I was using a few lines of code, and I just wanted to have everything in one function just to save some typing, but with my updated there's no need for that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new feature from PHP 5.6, it's called **Variadic functions**
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

```
function foo(...$arguments) {
    foreach ($arguments as $arg) {
        var_dump($arg);
    }
}

foo('1', 2, true, new DateTime('now'));
```

Comment: My problem is that I don't want to pass the arguments in that way, but I prefer to pass an array with properties, like in the example I shown, but thank you anyway

Comment: Maybe you can use the call_user_func_arr http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php , it allows to pass an array of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PHP built-in function     [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

Use it this way:

```
$var_array = array("color" => "blue",
                   "size"  => "medium",
                   "shape" => "sphere");
extract($var_array);
```

When you run `echo $color, $size, $shape;` it outputs:

```
blue, medium, sphere
```